# SNS publish and Firebase Save Data does nothing in AWS Node.JS Lambda

Tags: node.js, firebase, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, alexa-skills-kit

I have been trying to use Cloud Messaging with my Lambda Function to send push notifications.

At first I tried to use SNS linked to Firebase. But calling SNS.publish does nothing... no errors, no timeouts just seems to ignore the call. Here is a snippet of where it goes wrong:

```
const intentName = event.request.intent.name;

            // Dispatch to your skill's intent handlers
            if (intentName === 'Temperature') {
              getPatientTemperature(intent, context, 
                function (internalcontext, speechOutput) {

                    //sns
                    //var outmessage = {Display: speechOutput};
                    var sns = new AWS.SNS({region:'us-east-1'});
                    //console.log(sns);

                    console.log('sending push');
                    sns.publish({
                        Message: speechOutput,
                        TopicArn: "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:*************:MedicalAssistantDisplayUpdates",
                        Subject: "TestSNS"
                    }, function(err, data) {
                        //context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

                         console.log("SNS here 2");
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err.stack);
                            return;
                        }

                        console.log('push sent');
                        console.log(data);

                        console.log("SNS here 3");
                    });

                    context.succeed( buildResponse({}, buildSpeechletResponse("Sent",speechOutput, "no text", true)));


                    console.log("That's all folks");



                });
            } else {
            throw new Error('Invalid intent');
            }
```

It's full code:

```
/* eslint-disable  func-names */
/* eslint-disable  no-console */

//const Alexa = require('ask-sdk-core');

var mysql = require('mysql');
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host:   "********************",
        port:   "****",
        user:   "*******",
        password:   "*****",
        database:   "**************"
    });
//=========================================================================================================================================
//TODO: The items below this comment need your attention.
//=========================================================================================================================================

const SKILL_NAME = 'Medical Assistant';
const GET_TEMPERATURE_MESSAGE = '\'s temperature is ';
const HELP_MESSAGE = 'You can say tell me the latest tempearture of patient patient ID, or, you can say exit... What can I help you with?';
const HELP_REPROMPT = 'What can I help you with?';
const FALLBACK_MESSAGE = 'The Medical Assistant can\'t help you with that.  It can help you retrieve a patient\'s tempearture. What can I help you with?';
const FALLBACK_REPROMPT = 'What can I help you with?';
const STOP_MESSAGE = 'Goodbye!';



// --------------- Helpers that build all of the responses -----------------------

function buildSpeechletResponse(title, output, repromptText, shouldEndSession) {
    return {
        outputSpeech: {
            type: 'PlainText',
            text: output,
        },
        card: {
            type: 'Simple',
            title: `${title}`,
            content: `${output}`,
        },
        reprompt: {
            outputSpeech: {
                type: 'PlainText',
                text: repromptText,
            },
        },
        shouldEndSession,
    };
}

function buildResponse(sessionAttributes, speechletResponse) {
    return {
        version: '1.0',
        sessionAttributes,
        response: speechletResponse,
    };
}

function getPatientTemperature(intent, context, callback) {
    const cardTitle = intent.name;
    const PatientID = intent.slots.PatientID.value;
    console.log(PatientID);
    let repromptText = '';
    let sessionAttributes = {};
    const shouldEndSession = false;
    let speechOutput = '';


    console.log('Then run MySQL code:');

    //connection.connect(function(err) {
        console.log('Inside connection.connect() callback');
        //context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
        //if (!err) {
            console.log("Database is connected ... ");
            connection.query("SELECT Temperature, Patient_Name FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT c.Temperature, p.Patient_Name, c.Recorded_Time FROM ConsultationRecords c, Patients p WHERE (c.Patient_ID = p.Patient_ID) AND c.Patient_ID = '"+ PatientID +"' AND c.Temperature IS NOT NULL)AS Alias ORDER BY Recorded_Time DESC LIMIT 1) AS RequiredTemp",
                function(err, result) {
                    //connection.end();
                    console.log("Inside connection.query() callback")
                    if (!err) {
                        console.log("Query Successful! Ending Connection.");
                        //connection.end();
                        if (result.length > 0) {
                            if(result[0].Temperature == 'null'){

                            }
                            else{
                                speechOutput = result[0].Patient_Name+"'s temperature is "+result[0].Temperature;
                                console.log("Returning Response");
                            }

                        }
                        else{
                            speechOutput = "Patient ID not found in records";
                            console.log("Returning invalid ID Response");

                        }

                        callback(context, speechOutput);
                    } else {
                        console.log("Query error!");
                    }
                });
       // } else {
       //     console.log("Error connecting database ..." + err.message);
       //     connection.end();

       // }

        console.log("here end");


   // });


}

function getWelcomeResponse(context) {
    // If we wanted to initialize the session to have some attributes we could add those here.
    const sessionAttributes = {};
    const cardTitle = 'Welcome';
    const speechOutput = 'Welcome to Medical Assistant. ' +
        'You can ask for Patient information like Temperature';
    // If the user either does not reply to the welcome message or says something that is not
    // understood, they will be prompted again with this text.
    const repromptText = 'For example, say: what is the latest temparature of patient 1.';
    const shouldEndSession = false;

    console.log(`Send Welcome Response`);

    context.succeed(buildSpeechletResponse(cardTitle, speechOutput, repromptText, shouldEndSession));
}

exports.handler = (event, context) => {
    try {

        if (event.session.new) {
            // New Session
            console.log("NEW SESSION");
        }

        // Fix for hardcoded context from simulator
        //if(event.context && event.context.System.application.applicationId == 'applicationId'){
        //    event.context.System.application.applicationId = event.session.application.applicationId;
        //}


        switch (event.request.type) {

            case "LaunchRequest":
                console.log(`Launch Request`);

                getWelcomeResponse(context);
                console.log(`End Launch`);

                break;

            case "IntentRequest":
                // Intent Request
                console.log(`Intent Request`);

                const intent = event.request.intent;
                const intentName = event.request.intent.name;

                // Dispatch to your skill's intent handlers
                if (intentName === 'Temperature') {
                  getPatientTemperature(intent, context, 
                    function (internalcontext, speechOutput) {

                        //sns
                        //var outmessage = {Display: speechOutput};
                        var sns = new AWS.SNS({region:'us-east-1'});
                        //console.log(sns);

                        console.log('sending push');
                        sns.publish({
                            Message: speechOutput,
                            TopicArn: "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:**********:MedicalAssistantDisplayUpdates",
                            Subject: "TestSNS"
                        }, function(err, data) {
                            //context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

                             console.log("SNS here 2");
                            if (err) {
                                console.log(err.stack);
                                return;
                            }

                            console.log('push sent');
                            console.log(data);

                            console.log("SNS here 3");
                        });

                        context.succeed( buildResponse({}, buildSpeechletResponse("Sent",speechOutput, "no text", true)));


                        console.log("That's all folks");



                    });
                } else {
                throw new Error('Invalid intent');
                }

                break;

            case "SessionEndedRequest":
                // Session Ended Request
                console.log(`SESSION ENDED REQUEST`);
                break;

            default:
                context.fail(`INVALID REQUEST TYPE: ${event.request.type}`);

        }

    } catch (error) {
        context.fail(`Exceptiodn: ${error}`)
    }

};
```

After console.log('sending push'); it correctly runs context.succeed and the final console.log.

For my second attempt I tried to use the Firebase Admin SDK to update the firebase database (figuring I can store my messages there and then trigger a push notification from firebase when an insertion is made). I created a whole new Lambda function to test that and again.. just seems to ignore usersRef.set call. Here is the full code for that function:

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("medicalassistantviewer-firebase-adminsdk-7xw02-266915e453.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://****************.firebaseio.com"
});

// As an admin, the app has access to read and write all data, regardless of Security Rules
var db = admin.database();
var ref = db.ref();

var usersRef = ref.child("Messages");


exports.handler = (event, context) => {
    console.log("Let's start");
    context.succeed(usersRef.set({
          message2: {
            Message: "testing again",
            Token: "200"
          },
          message3: {
            Message: "and again",
            Token: "300"
          }
        }, function(err, data) {
            //context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

            console.log("messages not sent");
           if (err) {
               console.log(err.stack);
               return;
           }

           console.log('messages sent');
           console.log(data);

           console.log("here");
       }));

};
```

Comment: This issue was resolved. Nothing wrong with the code. The culprit was my VPC security group where I had only allowed MySQL traffic for outgoing. Worked after I changed it to ALL TRAFFIC.

Comment: You do not have to add SOLVED in the title of your question, you must post an answer and mark it as correct, this is the way to indicate that your question has been resolved in SO.